# How to identify \\hostName as a host and obtain the names of child items under \\hostName?

Tags: c#, attributes, identity, host

I have a remote host `\\foo` that serves up shares: `\\foo\a`, `\\foo\b`, and `\\foo\c`

On my local Win 7 client machine, when I bring up Windows Explorer and enter `\\foo` in the address bar, it obliges me by showing the names of the 3 shares. The Type attribute for each is "Share"

I have a C# program and I want it to mimic Windows Explorer. I have a method that accepts what should be the a local path name (e.g., `C:\x\y\z`), fully-qualified share name (e.g., `\\foo\a`), or host name (e.g., `\\foo`). The method is to get the names of the items (folder, share, file, 1st level only) contained within the folder, share, or host, just like Windows explorer

`File.Exists("\\foo")` and `Directory.Exists("\\foo")` both return false

`new DirectoryInfo("\\foo")` and `File.GetAttributes("\\foo")` throw an exception "The UNC path should be of the form \server\share"

The `Path` class seems designed to return just strings and not attributes

Given only the string `"\\foo"`, is there a class method/property that will identify it as a host or at least let me test it to see if it is a host and then obtain a list of names that are its children?

Comment: Have you tested to make sure it's actually reading it like a directory? i.e ``\\foo\``

Comment: when you say "it's", I assume you mean my C# program. It's not reading it like a directory. `Directory.Exists("\\foo")` returns false. This makes sense because it's not a directory. It's a host name, hence my question: `How to identify \\hostName as a host and obtain the names of child items under \\hostName?`

Comment: Yes, it answered my question